# Regex replace and divide

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I need to extract only numbers from a string and thus far I hadn't problems.

I used this code:

```
string test = "N.11 Test 11";
string example = Regex.Replace(test, @"[^\d]", "");
```

Output: "1111".

So.. How I can separate the two values ​​with a symbol?

Example: "11:11".

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Just match all digit sequences and join the resulting array with `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple approach not using replace would be something like this.

```
string test = "N.11 Test 11";
var result = string.Join(":", Regex.Matches(test, @"\d+").OfType<Match>());
```

Note that its better to use Regex variable instead of using static methods like `Regex.Matches`. if you want to use same pattern over and over its not elegant to create new regex every time. so this is better.

```
public static Regex digits = new Regex(@"\d+");
//...
var result = string.Join(":", digits.Matches(test).OfType<Match>());
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

use this regex: `[^\d]*(\d+).*?(\d+)` to group two numbers, then replace in `\1:\2`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:    

String test = "N.11 Test 11";

String example = test.replaceFirst( "\\s", ":" );
example = example.replaceAll( "[^:\\d]", "" );
System.out.println("The answer is " + example);
```